# Is there an alternative to LEFT JOIN in custom tables with WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two custom tables in the WordPress database.

```
table1:  
id | title | etc  

table2:  
id | table1_id | title | source | etc
```

I have this left join working perfectly:

```
select p.title as ptitle, e.id, e.title, e.source, e.etc
FROM table2 AS e
LEFT JOIN table1 AS p 
ON p.id = e.table1_id 
where e.table1_id = 1
```

which returns this:

```
ptitle1 | id1 |title1 | source1 | etc1
ptitle1 | id2 |title2 | source2 | etc2
ptitle1 | id3 |title3 | source3 | etc3
```

Is there a way of omitting so many repetitions of *ptitle*? Something like this:

```
ptitle1 | { (id1 |title1 | source1 | etc1), (id2 |title2 | source2 | etc2), (id3...) }
ptitle2 | { null }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this

Comment: As @Strawberry said, why? How are you going to easily parse the results if the rows are differently structured?

Comment: the result I want is an object like this:
`object { ptitle1 , array( array( id1, title1, source1, etc1),  array( id2, title2, source2, etc2) ) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED v.2**

I've changed the query to reflect change in LEFT JOIN order and also to show `object { ptitle, array( null ) }` situation - **data you needed is in the column `new_col`**:

```
select 
    p.title as ptitle, 
    CONCAT('object { ', p.title, ', array( ', IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('array(', e.id, ' | ', e.title, ' | ', e.source, ' | ', e.etc, ')') SEPARATOR ', '), 'null'), ' ) }') AS new_col
FROM 
    table1 AS p
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS e  
        ON p.id = e.table1_id 
where 
    p.id = 1
GROUP BY 
    p.title
```

Reffering to your comment, new_col is a string and I thought that you need it in this form because you will apply a parser on this text to interprete it and return proper object for you. 
For this case I think you would have to describe the situation more closely, for what exact reason you need this specific form of result with maybe some kind of exaample usage in wordpress api - I'm not sure of that for 100%.

Comment: There is no way end up in array/object what is on CONCAT, right?
watching table1.title2:
ptitle2 | { null }  if left join is empty.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Could you explain closer "There is no way end up in array/object what is on CONCAT, right?" ? I'm afraid I didn't understand though would like to help.

Comment: the result I want is an object like this: `object { ptitle1 , array( array( id1, title1, source1, etc1), array( id2, title2, source2, etc2) ) }`
something like wordpress returns the queries.

Comment: Please try the updated version of the query - as for the NULL problem, from construction of your query, since there is `LEFT JOIN table1 AS p`, the only join-caused NULL you may get is `p.title = NULL`. Maybe query restructure would be needed, I'm not sure?

Comment: yes, the left join should have been the other way around.

it works, but the result is a string, not an object.

Comment: This does what I wanted.   
Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem - I'm really glad the solution could be finally found. Thanks for patience :)